# Directive child element no scope update

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to update the attribute of a child element of my directive by hovering over one of the other child elements but the scope is not updated. I've referred to [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482), but can't figure out why it won't work:

I've tried adding scope.$apply() since it's updated inside the click event, but doesn't seem to work wherever I placed it.

Template:

```
<div ng-controller="DashboardCtrl">
    <svg country>
        <path province class="province" id="{{$index}}" ng-attr-d="{{p.d}}" ng-repeat="p in paths">
        </path>
        <use id="use" ng-xlink-href="#{{current.province}}" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('dashboard').controller("DashboardCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.paths = [{..snip..}]

}]);

angular.module("map-directive", [])
    .directive("country",function () {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            scope: {},
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.current = {};
                this.hovered = function (province_id) {
                    $scope.current.province = province_id;
                }
            }
        }
    }).directive("province", function () {
        return {
            require: "^country",
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, countryCtrl) {
                element.on("mouseover", function () {
                    countryCtrl.hovered(attrs.id);
                })
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem I can see right away is that you use ng-repeat, this creates a new scope and won't inherit from the parent scope - which is what you are hoping for.

Pass in an isolate scope value so the directive province so it will receive the value of id.

```
.directive("province", function () {
        return {
            require: "^country",
            scope: {
               id: '@'
            },
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, countryCtrl) {
                element.on("mouseover", function () {
                    countryCtrl.hovered(scope.id);
                })
            }
        }
    })
```

But I am not 100 percent sure it will be passed as the id is wrapped in {{}} and needs to be evaluated first before it can be passed in, but maybe as it's only done with mouseover it will work. Otherwise wrap it in a $timeout - which is kinda hacky - but then u can see what is happening.

Comment: The id is not a problem in the code, the hovered function receives the id just fine, the problem is that the scope update in the controller doesn't seem to trigger the binding in the <use> element

Comment: ok... then in my opinion i would pull this info into the dashboard controller so the scope can be inherited throughout the elements.